# Can't Build app Packages for UWP store submission

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, uwp

I have written a Xamarin.Forms application and now I want to deploy the UWP project to the store but I can't create app packages. 
When using Microsoft.NetCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform 6.2.2 or 6.2.0-preview I 
 in release mode, I constantly get this error :

> Payload contains two or more files with the same destination path 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll'. Source files: 
>   C:\Users\john.nuget\packages\runtime.win10-x86-aot.microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.2.0-preview1-26926-04\runtimes\win10-x86-aot\lib\uap10.0.15138\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll
>   C:\Users\john.nuget\packages\system.runtime.compilerservices.unsafe\4.5.0\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll    OfflineCurrencyConverter.UWP

But I followed the answer to this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/issues/925) saying I should downgrade the package to 6.1.9.

Doing this causes my application to build for ever... the build never stops.

But when I disable .NET Native Tool chain, it builds and run in release mode but packages can't still be created. Please does anyone have a solution ? I'm frustrated.

I feel wasted building a whole app and realizing it can't be packaged at the end for this UWP project.

Comment: did you tried to remove `\bin\debug` and `\bin\release` folders then Create app packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it took way longer than you expected to build in release mode, **use nuget version of .net native** by installing `Microsoft.Net.Native.Compiler` [package on nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Native.Compiler/) in your project and re-build it as usual. This solution solves the very same problem you have now in my experience.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I didn't know about this!

Answer (score 1):

Building app for .NET Native in release mode can take **a very long time**. It can even take as much as 10 minutes for larger apps. So make sure to give the compiler the time it needs. It might seem it is building forever, but it should definitely finish.

Comment: I know this, but mine took hours to build, and it never ended