# UWP: Access violation happens only in release mode

Tags: .net-core, uwp, release

I am new to UWP. I have just ported a quite complicated WPF app. It took me several weeks to figure out every difference and refactored a lot of code. However when I start to build and run in release mode I get an Access violation exception.

How is this even possible? Aren't debug and release execution supposed to be the same? How can I debug this problem if it occurs only in release?

If I turn native compilation off, the release build runs without a problem. However, when I try to install it on the device, a NetCore 2.2 debug framework is required. What is this debug framework and why cannot I run my release code without it?

I used to develop for AspNetCore and those things can run even on Linux. I really do not understand how is a UWP app cannot run on a Windows 10 tablet without a special debug framework.

I am kind of lost here. Any help or guidance is much appreciated. Thanks

EDIT:

As for the conclusion: I needed to create the app again from scratch. I started copying everything from the old app class by class. It was worth the effort not just because I refactored a lot of code :) but finally found what was causing the crash. I had a dependency in one of my libraries to an older version of System.ServiceModel.Primitives NuGet package. In Debug build, even with Native Compilation, the runtime managed to resolve the package. However, in Release it could not.

It was quite a journey that made me to develop a better software. However I could avoid it by releasing more often from the beginning, or the if the runtime would show more informative error messages about assembly resolution problems.

Comment: Try deleting the bin and obj build directories and let the project rebuild.  It's worth a shot

Comment: Thanks @JasonRoner I have already done that. Did not help. There must be some missing NULL check somewhere that I need to find.

Comment: Just to be sure, can you check if this method solves the problem you have? because it looks like a .Net native compiler problem to me.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54090790/7418444

Comment: @Littledoe, Thank you for the suggestion. Including the Microsoft.Net.Native.Compiler package partially solved the issue. The compilation was done in 3 mins for Release without any errors. However I could not run the app on my laptop - it did not do anything. I will try on an actual device later. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .NET Native compilation tends to cause problems for apps and it is recommended to try and run the application frequently in the release mode to catch potential issues as soon as possible. Usually any reflection-related code should be checked well, as those usually are the source of problems.

I would suggest going back in time (if you have some kind of source control) and try earlier builds of your app to pinpoint the time when the app stopped working. Alternatively, you can try commenting out parts of the code until the release build starts working. Finally, it is also possible to create a blank project and sequentially copy code and run it to locate the problem.

.NET Native is an annoying aspect of UWP app development and Microsoft is aware of this - the plan is .NET Native will no longer be required anymore soon (most likely before .NET 5 comes) and later there will be a more predictable replacement.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the situation. That is rather inconvenient, however if I were aware of the situation, it would have been less pain building release continuously during development than facing such an issue at the end.